# python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm is not working

Tags: python

**`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`** I am trying to run this code in my CMD from last three and half  days but again and again it showing **`'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`**  this error, I have **python-3.11.3-amd64** in my pc and I set the PATH many times but still I am getting same error.

I checked many solutions on StackOverflow and tried many suggestions but I did not get the solution.

I am using this library in my project.

Screenshot of the resume analyzer:

[image: resume analyzer]

Comment: Have you tried `python3.exe -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`?

Comment: Apart from that I recommend you use virtual environments e.g. [conda/miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/). This makes it much easier and cleaner to manage packages.

Comment: Yes,  python3.exe -m spacy download en_core_web_sm  is working